All Start & End dates are same in the phase
I am getting same start and end date in the phase although they have different values in the data table. I am using the Gantt 2.0 Deneb visual.
Same Start & End Date
Also, in the image the first row has two values even though they are from different phase. Is it because of them having same ID? How can I fix this issue as well.
I have tried to group them by phases and ID but that is rather giving phase in every row.
